# How to detect checkbox toggle change in RadGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, radgridview

I have winform application I want to populate a radgrid view on basis of another radgridview. I want to do this by checking a checkbox column, If the checkbox is checked I want to add an item to other radgridview and if it is unchecked I want to remove that item.

I am trying to achieve is that when the checked state of a CheckBox in one CellValueChanged event.

Comment: As an added suggestion you can just go directly to the `CheckBox.Checked` state instead of using `Events`. For example: `if (CheckBox1.Checked == True) { Place code here}`

Comment: Here the checkbox is gridview column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `RadGridView_ValueChanged` event. In this event if you have just clicked on checkbox column than if checkbox is checked its values is `on` otherwise `off`

If you are looping throgh the `checkbox column` then for `current row checkbox` value would be `on or off` and for other rows its value will be `true / false`

Comment: plz upvone if useful ;)